# Mysql server 5.7 not starting on windows 10 after latest update

Tags: mysql, windows

I am using mySql server 5.7 and it was working fine ever since it was installed. However, after the latest windows 10 home update over the weekend, the server just cant seem to start (either through the mySql notifier or through mySql Workbench)

Any help is appreciated.

Here's the screen shot of the error log file on mySQL workbench.[screenshot of error log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQExU.png)

Please help me out.

Also, here's the startup message log that i got when i tried to start the server form the workbench app.

```
2017-12-04 11:34:54 - Workbench will use cmd shell commands to start/stop this instance
2017-12-04 11:34:59 - Starting server...
2017-12-04 11:35:03 - Server start done.

FROM DESKTOP-JVD2PIE.err:
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Warning  option 'read_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 8192
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Warning  option 'read_rnd_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Warning  TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Warning  'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Note  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.20-log) starting as process 8716 ...
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Warning  InnoDB: innodb-page-size has been changed from the default value 16384 to 65536.
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Note  InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Note  InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Note  InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Note  InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Note  InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Note  InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Note  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  Note  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  ERROR  InnoDB: Data file '.\ibdata1' uses page size 16384, but the innodb_page_size start-up parameter is 65536
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  ERROR] InnoDB: Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0  of datafile '.\ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
    2017-12-04T06:04:59  0  ERROR  InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
    2017-12-04T06:05:00  0  ERROR  Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
    2017-12-04T06:05:00  0  ERROR  Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
    2017-12-04T06:05:00  0  ERROR  Failed to initialize plugins.
    2017-12-04T06:05:00  0  ERROR  Aborting
    2017-12-04T06:05:00  0  Note  Binlog end
    2017-12-04T06:05:00  0  Note  Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
    2017-12-04T06:05:00  0  Note  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
2017-12-04 11:35:05 - Checking server status...
2017-12-04 11:35:05 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2017-12-04 11:35:05 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)
2017-12-04 11:35:05 - Assuming server is not running
2017-12-04 11:35:09 - Checking server status...
2017-12-04 11:35:09 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2017-12-04 11:35:09 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)
2017-12-04 11:35:09 - Assuming server is not running
```

Thanks!

Dishant Shah

Comment: I would suggest you to save it's installed folder first and then re-install it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114057/mysql-5-7-service-not-start-after-windows-10-update/55114058#55114058

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the MySql's service was removed after the update. But you can back up your DataBase following these steps:

Go to the "**MySql directory**"/bin.

Execute the **mysqld.exe** file.
(It will open a 'instance' of the MySql temporary.)

Then you have to create an output **.bat** file with the following script:

/"**MySql directory**"/bin/mysqldump -u root -p"**password**" -P "**port**" "**Schemma's name**" > C:/"**some output directory**"/dump.sql

Now you have the back up on the dump.sql file

To restory data when you create a new MySql service, following this to restory data:

create an input **.bat** file with this script:

/"**MySql directory**"/bin/mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p"**password**" -P "**port**" "**Schemma's name**" < C:/"**the output directory**"/dump.sql

Ignore the "".

Your MySql is installed normmarly on the default directory?

Anynone knows the reason to Windows Update crashing the MySql service?

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest to backup your existing data. And reinstall It.

Stop mysqld.exe [End task]

Update file [my.ini]

---

[mysqld]

innodb_force_recovery=4;

--You can fill with (1/2/3/4/5/6)

---

Start service MYSQL57

-- Export DB

-- Reisntall Mysql