# MySql 5.7 Service not start after Windows 10 update

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-10

Mysql server 5.7 not starting on windows 10 after latest update

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this problem. If the HandyCreative solution doesn't work it might be a much simpler issue.  In the search bar type in IIS. Open the Internet Information Services program that shows up as a result. On the right hand side click STOP. If you have IIS running you can't run MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

- Stop mysqld.exe [End task]
- Update file [my.ini]

  ## ----------------------------------------------------

  [mysqld]

  innodb_force_recovery=4;

  --You can fill with (1/2/3/4/5/6)

  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

  ## ----------------------------------------------------
- Start service MYSQL57
- Process Create,Update,Delete will disable
- Do BackUp Mysqldumb.

  Does anyone have a good and simple solution

Answer (score 0):

yes, restart services like mysql, IIS by going -->run --> services.msc - restart service's in there. Can you look at the event logs when you try and start mysql. Is there any errors?